# Deleting sheets and pivot tables in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm trying to integrate the creation of a power pivot and pivot chart in VBA and have worked out a big part.
However, I am encountering a problem which I cannot seem to overcome

I create new worksheets where i create the Pivot and export it to PDF.
when this is done, i delete the pivottable and worksheet with:

```
Sub DeleteAllPivotTables()
    PURPOSE: Delete all other sheets and pivots
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Output" Then
            If sht.Name <> "Syntax" Then
                For Each pvt In sht.PivotTables
                    pvt.TableRange2.Clear
                Next pvt
                sht.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next sht
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I delete the sheet without the part of the macro for deleting the pivot tables, I encounter a run-time 1004 error. In my knowledge because the pivotname "PivotTable1" is already taken and not deleted with the macro.
When the sheet is already deleted, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about two steps. **1)** loop and delete all pivot tables in the workbook (don't need to loop through sheets for this since the workbook has it's own collection of pivot table objects). **2)** loop and delete all sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually deleting the PivotTable when you Clear it. If you want to delete it, you need to use a solution like [this](http://mariaevert.dk/vba/?p=116) or [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/518955-vba-delete-pivot-table.html). I've updated your code to include those solutions.

```
Sub DeleteAllPivotTables()
    PURPOSE: Delete all other sheets and pivots
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Output" Then
            If sht.Name <> "Syntax" Then
                For Each pvt In sht.PivotTables
                    pvt.Range(pvt.TableRange2.Address).Delete
                Next pvt
                sht.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next sht
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`1004` is an error that appears quite often in VBA. In your case, you are deleting `Worksheets`, without checking how many `Sheets` left do you have left.

If you only have 1 `Sheet` left (A `Sheet` is a `Worksheet` or a `Chart`) and you delete it, error `1004` comes. To avoid it, make sure that `Sheets.Count` is more than 1, before deleting:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Sheets.Count > 1 Then ws.Delete
    Next ws
End Sub
```