# Delete PivotTable using the PivotTables name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PivotTable called CurrencyPivot (TableName in VBA). Is there a simple way to delete the PT by using the table name specifically?

I'm hoping not to have to use the clear all function based on the columns the PivotTable is in. Seems like not best practice.

The reason I want to delete the PivotTable is so when I run my macro, if the PivotTable already exists, it will delete it and then run the code to recreate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah self answer...

```
wsCurrencies.PivotTables("CurrencyPivot").TableRange2.Clear
```

wsCurrencies is the codename for the worksheet

After some more digging, using this instead, not sure if any better than above, but hoping so

```
wsCurrencies.PivotTables("CurrencyPivot").TableRange2.Delete
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494265/deleting-sheets-and-pivot-tables-in-excel-with-vba) would suggest that `TableRange2.Clear` doesn't actually delete the table.

Comment: Just when I thought I was maybe smart... haha

So without the clear code above, if i run my macro I'll get an error right in the beginning of my code to create the pivot cache. But with the code, it clears the existing pivottable and will continue on with my code.

Hoping you can further explain what you mean by doesn't actually delete the table

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the rest of your code but the linked thread suggests that the pivot table name is not deleted when `.TableRange2.Clear` is called. Perhaps this is not relevant to your use case.

Comment: So basically if i push my macro-button, it will create a pivottable and add fields. If i push the button again, i'll get an error because it cant create a pivottable ontop of a pivottable. So in the beginning of my code i've added the code above. I've changed .clear to .delete, maybe that makes a difference but either way it allows the macro button to work. Ty!